# Simple PHP Script to Implemet a Counter to track number of software installation

Tags: php, database, tracking, counter

I want to implement a simple script which is hosted in a web server when called by a desktop application increments the value stored in simple text file or simple database.
I want to protect the counter with a password so that only my application can activate the script and increment the value.Please Help me out
How can i do this i have got the basic code for a counter

```
<?php
2   $counter = ("hitcounter.txt");
3   $hits = file($counter);
4   $hits[0]++;
5   $fp = fopen($counter , "w");
6   fputs($fp , "$hits[0]");
7   fclose($fp);
8   // echo $hits[0];
9   ?>
```

Comment: If you want password protection I'd rather use a database.

Comment: Set up a database and create a table to store your data, for example a name field and a value field. Save your password in the database `INSERT INTO data SET name = 'password', value = '12345'`, and store the hit count starting from 0 `INSERT INTO data SET name = 'hits', value = 0`. When you need to increase the counter you simply `UPDATE data SET value = value + 1 WHERE name = 'hits'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use basic [HTTP authentication on php](http://php.net/manual/en/features.http-auth.php).

Example from php.net

```
<?php
if (!isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'])) {
    header('WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="My Realm"');
    header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized');
    echo 'Text to send if user hits Cancel button';
    exit;
} else {
    // check $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'] and $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW']} 
    // and increase your counter here
}
?>
```

Comment: Im a .Net Developer.Can you plz make it clear.Can i authenticate in this manner(example) :mysite.com/counter.php:password:mypass

Comment: Its in HTTP specification. You should request the url as `http://username:password@example.com/counter.php`